# Is there any online ecommerce project architecture available in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, spring-mvc, project

i am new to java design patterns and i am building the ecommerce sit with spring mvc. but i am confused how to write various classes according to patterns.

i don't know where to put authenticate , confirmEmailAddress , addProdctCart , shoppingHistory like functions ,

so is there example of any site where i can find how divide the functions in classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java web frameworks tends to be more bare-bones than other web frameworks.

Rails give you convention-over-configuration and it's pretty easy to get up a data-driven/dynamic website up and running.

PHP offers several frameworks. Drupal, Wordpress, CodeIgniter, just to name a few.

I've used each of these, and each has their strength. To boil it down, I would say that in Java, you are cursed by too many options and flexibility and I would say the opposite of the other platforms.

The other platforms (non-Java) may offer methods like authenticate, confirmEmailAddress, addProdctCart, shoppingHistory that you could just fill in. You will not find this in Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you read through the [Spring Security tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html), it gives you a lot of what you're looking for: Spring MVC, security, Hibernate, etc. You can checkout the PetClinic sample app from their SVN repo.